# jQuery colorbox - get url parameter from clicked link

Tags: jquery, url, href, parameter-passing, colorbox

I am using Colorbox to load a contact form within an iframe.

However, I want the Colorbox url to be different than the html one, to serve up a different contact page for JS and non-JS users.

I do need to get the url parameter from the exact clicked link though.

HTML Code:

```
<a href="contact?id=XX" class="enquiryForm">
```

Colorbox code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.enquiryForm').colorbox({height:600, width:800, iframe:true, href: 'colorboxcontact?id=XX'});

});
```

Where 'contact' is the non-JS page and 'colorboxcontact' is the page to be loaded in the Colorbox iframe.

How can I extract the url parameter from the **clicked** link, and then add it to the 'colorboxcontact' href value in my jQuery call?

*** EDIT ***

Ok I've arrived at the following but still don't have it working. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

```
$('.enquiryForm').colorbox({
    height:600, 
    width:800, 
    iframe:true, 
      href: $('.enquiryForm').each(function() {
        newhref = 'colorboxcontact' + $(this).attr('href').split("?")[3];
        $(this).attr('href', newhref);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get specific query string info for url string you need this function found at:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)

slightly modified:

```
function getParameterByName(url, name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec(url);
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

so then you will end up with something like this:

```
$('.dialog-open').each(function() {
   $(this).colorbox({
     height: 600, 
     width: 800, 
     iframe: true, 
     href: "contact?id=" + getParameterByName($(this).attr("href"), "id")
   });
});
```

Comment: The 'Answer your Question' button doesn't seem to be working in Safari... anyway, thanks, I have already solved it like this:

Comment: $('.enquiryForm').each(function() {
    var loc = $(this).attr('href').split('?'), base = loc[0], query = '';
    if (loc[1]) {
    $(this).attr('href', 'colorboxcontact' + '?' + loc[1]);
        }
    else {
    $(this).attr('href', 'colorboxcontact?id=XX');
    }
  });

$('.enquiryForm').colorbox({
    height:600, 
    width:550, 
    iframe:true 
  });

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to get the value, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.enquiryForm').each(function() {
    $(this).colorbox({
      height: 600, 
      width: 800, 
      iframe: true, 
      href: $(this).attr("href")
    });
  });
});
```

[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) gives you access to each `<a>` as you loop over them via `this`.  If you don't care if it's a fully qualified url or not, you can replace `$(this).attr("href")` with `this.href` (IE will fully qualify this), like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.enquiryForm').each(function() {
    $(this).colorbox({ height: 600, width: 800, iframe: true, href: this.href });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Nick - I'd tried something similar to this and it gets the whole url, but what I am actually trying to do is grab the '?=XX' parameter and append it to a different url, if that makes sense...

Comment: So instead of 'contact?id=XX', it becomes 'COLORBOXcontact?id=XX'. This is because I have a different page template for the colorbox form standard form for non-JS users (excluding headers, etc). Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps a simple approach would be to set the href to a function that returns the link.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.enquiryForm').colorbox({
        height:600, 
        width:800, 
        iframe:true, 
        href: function(){
            return $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
});
```